# Magento2 + UI component xml file stop working as mode of deployment change

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent, fatal-error

Below is listing XML file under UI component which is working fine in default deploy mode, but its suddenly stop working in as mode change to developer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Mage2 Developer, Inc. All rights reserved.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">inquiry_listing_index.inquiry_listing_index_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="add">
                <url path="*/*/new"/>
                <class>primary</class>
                <label translate="true">Add New Inquiry</label>
            </button>
        </buttons>
        <spinner>inquiry_listing_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>inquiry_listing_index.inquiry_listing_index_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="inquiry_listing_index_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <storageConfig>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">inquiry_id</param>
            </storageConfig>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
        <aclResource>Mage2_Inquiry::inquiry</aclResource>
        <dataProvider class="Mage2\Inquiry\Ui\Component\DataProvider" name="inquiry_listing_index_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>inquiry_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <settings>
                <templates>
                    <filters>
                        <select>
                            <param name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</param>
                            <param name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</param>
                        </select>
                    </filters>
                </templates>
            </settings>
            <filterSelect name="store_id" provider="${ $.parentName }">
                <settings>
                    <captionValue>0</captionValue>
                    <options class="Mage2\Inquiry\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Inquiry\Options"/>
                    <label translate="true">Store View</label>
                    <dataScope>store_id</dataScope>
                    <imports>
                        <link name="visible">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                    </imports>
                </settings>
            </filterSelect>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="delete">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete selected items?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="inquiry/inquiry/massDelete"/>
                    <type>delete</type>
                    <label translate="true">Delete</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
            <action name="edit">
                <settings>
                    <callback>
                        <target>editSelected</target>
                        <provider>inquiry_listing_index.inquiry_listing_index.inquiry_listing_columns_editor</provider>
                    </callback>
                    <type>edit</type>
                    <label translate="true">Edit</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="inquiry_listing_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="inquiry/inquiry/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">inquiry_id</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">inquiry_listing_index.inquiry_listing_index.inquiry_listing_columns.ids</param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">inquiry_listing_index.inquiry_listing_index.inquiry_listing_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <settings>
                <indexField>inquiry_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="inquiry_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="name">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Customer Name</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="email">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Email</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="status" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <options class="Mage2\Inquiry\Model\Source\Status"/>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Status</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Mage2\Inquiry\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\InquiryActions">
            <settings>
                <indexField>inquiry_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Getting error

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The XML in file
>   "/var/www/html/2-3/app/code/Mage2/Inquiry/view/adminhtml/ui_component/inquiry_listing_index.xml"
>   is invalid: Element 'listing': Character content other than whitespace
>   is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'. Line: 7
>
> Element 'columns': Character content other than whitespace is not
>   allowed because the content type is 'element-only'. Line: 95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the comment section. Ex.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">inquiry_listing_index.inquiry_listing_index_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="add">
                <url path="*/*/new"/>
                <class>primary</class>
                <label translate="true">Add New Inquiry</label>
            </button>
        </buttons>
        <spinner>inquiry_listing_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>inquiry_listing_index.inquiry_listing_index_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="inquiry_listing_index_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <storageConfig>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">inquiry_id</param>
            </storageConfig>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
        <aclResource>Mage2_Inquiry::inquiry</aclResource>
        <dataProvider class="Mage2\Inquiry\Ui\Component\DataProvider" name="inquiry_listing_index_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>inquiry_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <settings>
                <templates>
                    <filters>
                        <select>
                            <param name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</param>
                            <param name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</param>
                        </select>
                    </filters>
                </templates>
            </settings>
            <filterSelect name="store_id" provider="${ $.parentName }">
                <settings>
                    <captionValue>0</captionValue>
                    <options class="Mage2\Inquiry\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Inquiry\Options"/>
                    <label translate="true">Store View</label>
                    <dataScope>store_id</dataScope>
                    <imports>
                        <link name="visible">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                    </imports>
                </settings>
            </filterSelect>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="delete">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete selected items?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="inquiry/inquiry/massDelete"/>
                    <type>delete</type>
                    <label translate="true">Delete</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
            <action name="edit">
                <settings>
                    <callback>
                        <target>editSelected</target>
                        <provider>inquiry_listing_index.inquiry_listing_index.inquiry_listing_columns_editor</provider>
                    </callback>
                    <type>edit</type>
                    <label translate="true">Edit</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="inquiry_listing_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="inquiry/inquiry/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">inquiry_id</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">inquiry_listing_index.inquiry_listing_index.inquiry_listing_columns.ids</param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">inquiry_listing_index.inquiry_listing_index.inquiry_listing_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <settings>
                <indexField>inquiry_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="inquiry_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="name">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Customer Name</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="email">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Email</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="status" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <options class="Mage2\Inquiry\Model\Source\Status"/>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Status</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Mage2\Inquiry\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\InquiryActions">
            <settings>
                <indexField>inquiry_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: Sorry not working that

Comment: Did you copy my modified code?

Comment: working fine, but what you have done ?

Comment: I ran it through winmerge, there's some whitespace at the end of the very last tag. Hopefully this helps someone scratching their head here!